# Enable offline working for Microsoft Office addin for Mac

Tags: office-js

I am working on a cross-platform addin for Microsoft Word using the HTML/JavaScript approach and have an addin that works fine on both Windows and Mac.

I have enabled the addin to work when a machine is offline by using an HTML5 .appcache manifest. This works fine on Windows, but on Word for Mac the addin does not load at all when the machine is offline, with just the following error displayed:

[image: Error - Sorry, we can't load the add-in. Please make sure you have network]

I am on Word for Mac v15.37.

Are offline addins supported in this way on Office for Mac, and if so is there anything I need to do to enable them?